# How to use cmd.parameters.add("@ID") SQL, VB.NET

Tags: sql, vb.net

```
 Dim connect As String = "Data Source=DESKTOP-D32ONKB;Initial Catalog=Attendance;Integrated Security=True"
        Using conn As New SqlConnection(connect)
            Dim dt As DataTable = New DataTable()
            Dim sql As String = "SELECT ID,Name,Class,Date FROM stuattrecordAMPM"
            Using command As New SqlCommand(sql, conn)
                Using adapter As New SqlDataAdapter(command)
                    Dim i As Integer = 0
                    For i = 0 To dt.Rows.Count - 1
                        Dim sy As String = dt.Rows(i).Item(0).ToString
                    Next
                    'command.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32(TextBox1.Text)
                    adapter.Fill(dt)
                    TextBox1.Text = dt(0)(0)
                End Using
            End Using
        End Using
```

This code working properly asper my expectation. When I use "where ID=@ID" in sqlcommand It's showing error: 'Input string was not in a correct format.'

```
        Dim connect As String = "Data Source=DESKTOP-D32ONKB;Initial Catalog=Attendance;Integrated Security=True"
        Using conn As New SqlConnection(connect)
            Dim dt As DataTable = New DataTable()
            Dim sql As String = "SELECT ID,Name,Class,Date FROM stuattrecordAMPM where ID=@ID"
            Using command As New SqlCommand(sql, conn)
                Using adapter As New SqlDataAdapter(command)
                    Dim i As Integer = 0
                    For i = 0 To dt.Rows.Count - 1
                        Dim sy As String = dt.Rows(i).Item(0).ToString
                    Next
                    command.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32(TextBox1.Text)
                    adapter.Fill(dt)
                    TextBox1.Text = dt(0)(0)
                End Using
            End Using
        End Using
```

In this code I'm getting error. Could someone help me how to declare "@ID". Thank you..
Please check the error description.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HEBAW.jpg)

Comment: That doesn't look like an SQL problem. `Convert.ToInt32(TextBox1.Text)` seems to have failed.

Comment: Can you debug the code and output the value for `TextBox1.Text` ?

Comment: You have to validate the input (e.g., with `Integer,TryParse()`) before you try and create a query with invalid values

Comment: @AnelHodžić, Output value shows TextBox1.Text

Answer (score 1):

That's maybe because you are trying to add parameters using the statement of the adapter.
Try this:

```
Dim idValue As Int = Convert.ToInt32(TextBox1.Text)
Dim dt As DataTable = New DataTable()  
Dim connect As String = "Data Source=DESKTOP-D32ONKB;Initial Catalog=Attendance;Integrated Security=True"
Using conn As New SqlConnection(connect)        
    Dim sql As String = "SELECT ID,Name,Class,Date FROM stuattrecordAMPM where ID=@ID"
    Using command As New SqlCommand(sql, conn)
        command.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = idValue
            Using adapter As New SqlDataAdapter(command)                
                adapter.Fill(dt)                
            End Using            
    End Using
End Using
Dim i As Integer = 0
For i = 0 To dt.Rows.Count - 1
    Dim sy As String = dt.Rows(i).Item(0).ToString
Next
TextBox1.Text = dt(0)(0)
```

If you want to change the way you using to parse string to int:

```
Dim idValue As Int = Integer.Parse(TextBox1.Text)
    Dim dt As DataTable = New DataTable()  
    Dim connect As String = "Data Source=DESKTOP-D32ONKB;Initial Catalog=Attendance;Integrated Security=True"
    Using conn As New SqlConnection(connect)        
        Dim sql As String = "SELECT ID,Name,Class,Date FROM stuattrecordAMPM where ID=@ID"
        Using command As New SqlCommand(sql, conn)
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("ID", idValue)
                Using adapter As New SqlDataAdapter(command)                
                    adapter.Fill(dt)                
                End Using            
        End Using
    End Using
    Dim i As Integer = 0
    For i = 0 To dt.Rows.Count - 1
        Dim sy As String = dt.Rows(i).Item(0).ToString
    Next
    TextBox1.Text = dt(0)(0)
```

Comment: There's no reason to *believe* that `Integer.Parse(TextBox1.Text)` will succeed: since it's probably User input, it's bound to fail in a way or another. You validate the input first, then use the validated / converted input as the value of a Parameter -- You should not suggest using `[Parameters].AddWithValue()` in this context, you should use `[Parameters].Add()`

Comment: Yes I also think this is not the main problem. Methu maybe you should try to parse it before you connecting to database just like Jimi says. But at the end you should do the things about DataTable, after you fill the datatable.

Comment: @DevrimMertYöyen, [Parameters].Add() is showing the same error message. Could you tell me how to work on this issue. Thank you...

Comment: @methu I edited codes as Jimi adviced. Can you please try them again. If its still not working please put your TextBox1.Text to a messagebox or log and let us see

Comment: @DevrimMertYöyen, Its showing the same error: "Input string was not in a correct format". Could you help on this. Thank you...

Comment: @methu I need to see your _input_ . Are you sure that string value converted to int **succesfuly**?

Comment: @DevrimMertYöyen, Its converted string to int but showing error, I attached screenshot could you check it once. Thank you...

Comment: @methu Probably the value of the textbox is not okay to convert it to the int. You can check it usign this lines,
'int idValue;
if(Int32.TryParse(textbox1.Text, out idValue)
{
  // t has ben set with the integer converted
  // add here the code that uses the t variable
}
else
{
  // textbox1.Text doesn't contain a valid integer
  // Add here a message to your users about the wrong input....
  // (if needed)
}'
Can you please also share the input of the textbox. It should be only numbers. Please be sure, there is no chars other than the numbers. Maybe it can be some char like ' '

Comment: @DevrimMertYöyen, Thank you I'm working on your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like in your broken code you need/want to have multiple "id" or more than one value. You can do this, but you ALSO then have to add the parameters to the source SQL string.

You can't just add, or have multiple @ID values for the one "@ID".
If you want more than one ID value in the same SQL query, then you have to add multiple "@id1" then "@id2" and so on to the SQL text for this to work.

So, if you have one "@ID" then fine.

However, if you have say id 2, 134, 222, then you would have to add each parameter to the SQL string.

You can do it this way:

```
 dim strSQL as string = "SELECT * FROM MyTable"
 dim strWhere as string = ""

 dim cmdSQL as New Sqlcommand("", new Sqlconnection("con string here")

  ' add first @id
  strWhere = "@ID1"
  cmd.SQL.Parameters.Add("@ID1", SqlDbType.Int).Value = 124

  ' add 2nd @!id
  strWhere &= ",@ID2"
  cmd.SQL.Parameters.Add("@ID2", SqlDbType.Int).Value = 456

  ' and so on and so on
  cmdSQL.CommandText = strSQL & " WHERE ID IN (" & strWhere & ")"
  dim rstData as new DataTable()
  cmdSQL.connection.Open()
  rstData.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader())
```

Note VERY interesting that you can create the SQL command object, and are 100% free to add as many new parameters as possible to the cmdSQL object, and EVEN do so without having the SQL command/text set for the SQL command object.

However, you eventually will have to setup/provide/have the sql shoved into that command object. So, build up the multiple "@id1, @id2" etc., and then shove that whole correct SQL string into the cmdSQL object, and it will work.

However, as noted, you are free to add as many parameters to the cmdSQL object, and even do so without having the SQL made/set/created for the cmdSQL object. They thus can be created 100% independent of the existing sql string/text (or better said lack of that SQL string during the parameter adding process).

Comment: There were five separate misspellings of keyword/property/method names in the code example here. I have tried to repair them, but please verify.